# What's the status of this border crossing between Thailand and Cambodia?

Tags: borders, thailand, identify-this, visas-on-arrival, cambodia

Google Maps has suggested [this crossing from Thailand to Cambodia](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Unnamed+Rd,+Tambon+Phupha+Mok,+Amphoe+Kantharalak,+Chang+Wat+Si+Sa+Ket,+Thailand/@14.4339183,104.8108152,15z/data=!4m33!1m30!4m29!1m6!1m2!1s0x31246889c7572883:0x820916f507aac39b!2sPhonepaseuth+Guest+House,+23+Manthatulath+Road+Ban+XiengYrun+Vientiane+Laos,+Vientiane+01000,+Laos!2m2!1d102.6066828!2d17.9637363!1m6!1m2!1s0x31237641e81572a3:0x5ba46d1afe6c1f17!2sUdon+Thani,+Mueang+Udon+Thani+District,+Udon+Thani,+Thailand!2m2!1d102.8158924!2d17.3646969!1m6!1m2!1s0x311306a4b09f7d2d:0x71e1eb3b5dd02f0a!2sPreah+Rumkel,+Cambodia!2m2!1d105.8525154!2d13.8762769!1m6!1m2!1s0x31097f0e1c5aa081:0xb28943ebbf033219!2sAngkor+Borei,+Cambodia!2m2!1d104.9768543!2d10.9920135!3e0!3m1!1s0x31114e44b688ffa9:0x472014c234414df8) located at `14.4339183,104.8108152` but I'm having trouble finding information about it.

1. Which name(s) does it generally go by?
2. Is it an international border, meaning it's open to non-locals?
3. Are Cambodian visas-on-arrival available here?

The closest place names on the Thai side are *Nong Yai* and *Ang Kep Nam Huai Khanun*, but searching with those has not yielded anything useful. I'm still looking for place names on the Cambodian side.

Comment: FWIW, satellite view on Google Maps doesn't show any obvious indication of buildings, widening lanes, traffic control, or other signs of an official border, in the immediate vicinity of either side of the border. The images are blurry, though, and such a checkpoint isn't always directly on the geographic border, so it may not mean much.

Comment: Yes either or both of my computer and my internet were horribly slow when I was trying to check. But some remote border posts in the developing world are not much more than a couple of huts on each side and a gate or two with all staff coming and going in just one or two cars or motorbikes and few people crossing. But also Google is sometimes wrong (-:

Comment: Google Street View is available on the Thai side up to a short distance from the border. You can find this checkpoint about 4km before the border. I can't see any obvious signs indicating a customs or immigration checkpoint, but it seems to be in use: https://www.google.com/maps/@14.4085506,104.79185,3a,75y,358.63h,72.59t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sdjs8mcIDZKR13w-AIr5okA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1

Comment: I think this is close to the Preah Vihaer temple, which has seen bloody conflict recently, between Cambodia and Thailand.

Comment: @MastaBaba: It is kinda close to Preah Vihear but there's another one right next to it. The conflict is a few years ago now and recent reports say it's fine to go there now. And there definitely is VOA available at that crossing.

Comment: Sure. I'm just giving a factoid. Voice of America?

Comment: VOA = Visa On Arrival (-:

Comment: I will answer only the first question. The location's name is Phu Bak Phrik.

Comment: @hippietrail any chance you can update after all these years?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Unfortunately I didn't get anywhere near the same area on my recent trip.

Comment: For what it's worth:  given those waypoints, Google Maps now routes you through the Aan Mah Border Crossing, about 15 km to the west of the road crossing at `14.4339183,104.8108152`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: In my experience Google Maps very often routes around border crossings that are 100% open too, so I wouldn't put enough faith in it to base an answer upon. I had to work around Google doing this plenty of times when working out my routes between countries on recent trips. Seems to be a general quirk of Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the section *Interesting facts about this location / Cambodian–Thai border dispute* of [this article](http://trip-suggest.com/thailand/sisaket/ban-phu-pha-mok/),

> the Cambodian–Thai border dispute began in June 2008 as the latest round of a century-long dispute between Cambodia and Thailand involving the area surrounding the 11th-century Preah Vihear Temple, located in the Dângrêk Mountains between the Choam Khsant district in the Preah Vihear province of northern Cambodia and the Kantharalak district in the Sisaket province of Northeastern Thailand.

Preah Vihear Temple here cited is less than 20 miles from **Phupha Mok** or **Phu Pha Mok** (`14.4339183,104.8108152`).

On the Cambodian side, the closest points of interest may be this [bunker from civil war](https://goo.gl/maps/MPAPmxjUxPc2QFUQ7), then [Bosbov Waterfall](https://goo.gl/maps/37JyrofjbHmpxVRx9). The Eco-Global Museum and the archeological sites called [Aur Krauch](https://goo.gl/maps/p9NsgDDPyuv5iY8WA) and [Thmom Peang](https://goo.gl/maps/qKD7AaKCCNGstRCV7) are some 20 miles on the south.